# CSS - responsive content including text

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create following, my goal is to display it exactly like this on whatever screen resolution:

[image: slide]

I came up with following HTML:

```
<div id="banner-homepage">
        <img class="pen1" src="img/pen.png" alt="">
        <img class="pen2" src="img/pen.png" alt="">
        <img class="pravitko" src="img/pravitko.png" alt="">
        <img class="kruzitko" src="img/kruzitko.png" alt="">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="banner-content">
                <h2><?php echo $atts['banner_title'];?></h2>
                <?php echo $atts['banner_content']?>
            </div>
            <div class="counter">
                <img class="pocitadlo" src="img/pocitadlo.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The CSS I have is:

```
#banner-homepage {
    background: url("../img/home_banner_bg.png");
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#banner-homepage .container {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 25%;
}

#banner-homepage .banner-content, #banner-homepage .counter {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.pen1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 20%;
    -ms-transform: rotate(40deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(40deg);
    width: 15%;
    height: auto;
}

.pen2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    bottom: -10%;
    width: 15%;
    height: auto;
}

.pravitko {
    position: absolute;
    right: -10%;
    top: 5%;
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
}

.kruzitko {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10%;
    bottom: 5%;
    width: 15%;
    height: auto;
}

.pocitadlo {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

This is far from perfect, as the text is not resized. My goal is to have the banner resized, so it looks the same wey on whatever device you look at it...

What is the correct markup to have the banner resized, including text?

Comment: Is SEO a concern? If not, an easy way to do this would be to just make it an image and then set `max-width:100%;`

Comment: The information in there is entered in Wordpress, no chance to set this as image...

Comment: What does it being entered in Wordpress have to do with the ability to replace it with an image?

Comment: I believe the core question here is, _"How can I achieve **responsive text size**?"_ You can use a plugin jQuery plugin like [FlowType](http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/), use `vw` for your `font-size` or a handful of media queries to set the `font-size`.

Comment: All the text is dynamicaly generated. The numbers are also dynamic counter. The button text and link is dynamic...

Comment: @hungerstar Not really - I hoped there's some way to build fully resposive row with dynamic content, that automatically resizes - ie., in Wordpress Revolution slider I can just check "responsive slider" and all the elements inside are automatically resized...

Comment: Read up on [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). You will have to manually change the sizing and positioning of each element at each breakpoint you include.

Comment: @user1049961 you stated, _"What is the correct markup to have the banner re-sized, including text?"_ How does that not include font re-sizing (i.e. _responsive text size_)? _WP Revolution Slider_ is using JavaScript to resize the text.